Spring Boot Application with Weka Predictions Works on the First Day After Build, But Fails on Subsequent Days
I’m using Spring Boot to develop an application that predicts data using Weka and PostgreSQL. The predictions run daily at 7:00 AM using the @Scheduled annotation. After building and running the project, the predictions work perfectly on the first day. However, on subsequent days, the predictions fail without any apparent errors.
@Component
public class WEKAGPP {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WEKAGPP.class);
    public List<Double> calculate() {
         List<Double> predictions = new ArrayList<>();
        
        String url = "";
        String user = "";
        String password = "";
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmtOrc = null;
        Statement stmtBop = null;

        try {
           
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

           
            stmtOrc = conn.createStatement();
            String sqlQueryHistoryOrc = "SELECT _0brs_tt306_0brs_tt306_pv_out, ft0499_ft0499_pv_out, tt1150_tt1150_pv_out, gen_active_power_diris_gen_active_power_pv_out, zaman_etiketi_tz FROM public.history_orc_r1";
            ResultSet rsOrc = stmtOrc.executeQuery(sqlQueryHistoryOrc);

            stmtBop = conn.createStatement();
            String sqlQueryHistoryBop = "SELECT _0hps_tit_305_ma_pv_out, zaman_etiketi_tz FROM public.history_bop_r1";
            ResultSet rsBop = stmtBop.executeQuery(sqlQueryHistoryBop);

           
            Attribute tt306 = new Attribute("_0brs_tt306_0brs_tt306_pv_out");
            Attribute ft0499 = new Attribute("ft0499_ft0499_pv_out");
            Attribute tt1150 = new Attribute("tt1150_tt1150_pv_out");
            Attribute hps305 = new Attribute("_0hps_tit_305_ma_pv_out");
            Attribute activePower = new Attribute("gen_active_power_diris_gen_active_power_pv_out");

            Instances data = new Instances("TrainingData", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(tt306, ft0499, tt1150, hps305, activePower)), 0);

           
            while (rsOrc.next() && rsBop.next()) {
                double[] values = new double[5];
                values[0] = rsOrc.getDouble("_0brs_tt306_0brs_tt306_pv_out");
                values[1] = rsOrc.getDouble("ft0499_ft0499_pv_out");
                values[2] = rsOrc.getDouble("tt1150_tt1150_pv_out");
                values[3] = rsBop.getDouble("_0hps_tit_305_ma_pv_out");
                values[4] = rsOrc.getDouble("gen_active_power_diris_gen_active_power_pv_out");

                DenseInstance instance = new DenseInstance(1.0, values);
                data.add(instance);
            }
            data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

           
            int trainSize = (int) Math.round(data.numInstances() * 0.7);
            int testSize = data.numInstances() - trainSize;
            Instances trainingData = new Instances(data, 0, trainSize);
            Instances testData = new Instances(data, trainSize, testSize);

          
            RandomForest rf = new RandomForest();
            String[] options = {"-I", "100", "-K", "3", "-depth", "5"};
            rf.setOptions(options);
            rf.buildClassifier(trainingData);

           
            double sumSquaredTotal = 0;
            double sumSquaredResidual = 0;
            double meanActualValue = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < testData.numInstances(); i++) {
                meanActualValue += testData.instance(i).classValue();
            }
            meanActualValue /= testData.numInstances();

            for (int i = 0; i < testData.numInstances(); i++) {
                double actualValue = testData.instance(i).classValue();
                double predictedValue = rf.classifyInstance(testData.instance(i));
                sumSquaredTotal += Math.pow(actualValue - meanActualValue, 2);
                sumSquaredResidual += Math.pow(actualValue - predictedValue, 2);
            }

            double rSquared = 1 - (sumSquaredResidual / sumSquaredTotal);


           
            LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            for (int day = 0; day <= 4; day++) {
                LocalDate queryDate = today.plusDays(day);
                for (int hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
                    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(queryDate, LocalTime.of(hour, 0));
                    String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter);

                    String sqlQueryWeather = "SELECT dis_ortam_sicaklik FROM public.weather " +
                            "WHERE DATE(datetime) = '" + queryDate + "' " +
                            "AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datetime) = " + hour +
                            " ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 1";

                    Statement stmtWeather = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rsWeather = stmtWeather.executeQuery(sqlQueryWeather);

                    if (rsWeather.next()) {
                        double futureTemperature = rsWeather.getDouble("dis_ortam_sicaklik");

                        double[] futureValues = new double[5];
                        futureValues[0] = 0;
                        futureValues[1] = 0;
                        futureValues[2] = futureTemperature;
                        futureValues[3] = 0;
                        futureValues[4] = Double.NaN;

                        DenseInstance futureInstance = new DenseInstance(1.0, futureValues);
                        futureInstance.setDataset(data);

                        double prediction = rf.classifyInstance(futureInstance);
                        predictions.add(prediction);
                      
                        logger.info("Datetime: " + formattedDateTime + 
                                           ", Active Power: " + prediction + 
                                           ", Temperature: " + futureTemperature);

                      
                        String insertPrediction = "INSERT INTO predictions (datetime, prediction_value, predicted_temperature) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertPrediction)) {
                            pstmt.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime));
                            pstmt.setDouble(2, prediction);
                            pstmt.setDouble(3, futureTemperature);
                            pstmt.executeUpdate();
                        }
                        
                    }
                    rsWeather.close();
                    stmtWeather.close();
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (stmtOrc != null) stmtOrc.close();
                if (stmtBop != null) stmtBop.close();
                if (conn != null) conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return predictions;
    }
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 7 * * ?")
public void predict() {
    logger.info("Start: "+Thread.currentThread().getName() +" time: "+LocalDateTime.now());

    List<Double> predictions = wekagpp.calculate();

    for (Double prediction : predictions) {
        logger.info("Calculated Values: " + prediction);
    }
    
    logger.info("End: "+Thread.currentThread().getName() +" time: "+LocalDateTime.now());
}

The method is triggered by the @Scheduled annotation as follows:
@Service
public class CalculatedOrcService {
   private WEKAGPP wekagpp;
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CalculatedOrcService.class);
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 7 * * ?")
    public void predict() {
        logger.info("Start: "+Thread.currentThread().getName() +" time: "+LocalDateTime.now());

        List<Double> predictions = wekagpp.calculate();

        for (Double prediction : predictions) {
            logger.info("Calculated Values: " + prediction);
        }
        
        logger.info("End: "+Thread.currentThread().getName() +" time: "+LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}

What I Have Checked:

The scheduled task runs successfully on the first day after the
application is deployed.
No exceptions or errors are logged in subsequent executions.
All required data is present in the PostgreSQL database and
accessible at the scheduled execution time.

What Could Be the Issue?

The connection probably became inactive for too long and the server disconnected it (happens with MySQL as well). Looking at the documentation of the JDBC driver, you could try the tcpKeepAlive parameter whether it solves the problem.
